# i am getting error "Missing { inserted. ...{B_{j\rightarrow i,t}} = {\left({\sum_{i^'"

Tags: math-mode, errors

```
\begin{equation}  
{B_{j\rightarrow i,t}} = {\left({\sum_{i^'} \in 
V_j\backslash i} B_{i{^'}\rightarrow j,t}\right)} \text{mod2}
\end{equation}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Off-topic: Do yourself a favor and don't encase larger math "molecules" in curly braces. E.g., why write `{B_{j\rightarrow i,t}}` if `B_{j\rightarrow i,t}` will do just as well -- and is, arguably, easier to read and (if necessary) debug.

Answer (score 3):

The full error message which you don't show, shows the exact location

```
! Missing { inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   ^
l.11 {B_{j\rightarrow i,t}} = {\left({\sum_{i^'
```

You should use `i'` not `i^'` which expands to `i^^{\prime}` and so is a double superscript.